# CSS2 version of height: calc(100% - 18px)

Tags: html, css

How can I do `height: calc(100% - 18px);` in CSS2? I have 3 `div` on a page.

```
<body>
    <div id="top">top</div>
    <div id="middle">middle</div>
    <div id="bottom">bottom</div>
</body>
```

- I want `top` to be 100% height minus `200px`
- I want `middle` to be `200px` and be right below `top`
- I want `bottom` to be right after `bottom`

The idea is that `top` and `middle` take up 100% of the browser window when the scroll bar is at the very top but the user should be able to scroll down to see `bottom`. And when the user scrolls `top` and `bottom` are still the same size (unless the user resizes the window).

I want to do this without JavaScript and it needs to be CSS2 cause we do not have a CSS3 compliant browser yet.

Comment: Are you sure? [`calc()` was supported as far back as IE9.](https://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

Comment: Partially supported by IE9, fully supported from IE10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a mix of negative margins and padding alongside `box-sizing: border-box`.

**Note:** In the below example I've used `50px` instead of `200px` as `200px` was a bit too large for the snippet output. You'll want to change the instances of `-50px` and `50px` with `-200px` and `200px` for your desired output.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#top {
  background: tomato;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#middle {
  background: cornflowerblue;
  height: 50px;
}

#bottom {
  background: papayawhip;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">top</div>
<div id="middle">middle</div>
<div id="bottom">bottom</div>
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you!